# Calculating MAX from specific date range on a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been struggling for 6 hours on this and it's driving me mad. I've given in an come for help...

I'm playing with stock prices and have rows of trade prices (asking price, datetime, name etc.) in 10 min intervals. I want to get a list of each trade, and how high that trade got within the next hour of trades.

Below is what I've been playing with so far. I want to add a 'max' column that returns the MAX price. - currently the below query returns all the trades in the `JOIN` instead (duplicate `c.id`'s) instead of a single trade with a MAX column.

If I use JOIN with a `limit 1` I get NULL values due to `a.market = c.market`, If I use MAX() I get grouping errors and no matter what I do I can't make it work. ql_mode=only_full_group_by is also on if that alters any answers.

Sample data/query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c61f4/1

```
SELECT 
c.id, 
c.ask AS trade_cost_at_time, 
c.timestamp, 
a.ask AS next_hour_top_price,
a.timestamp AS next_hour_top_price_time 
FROM trade_data c
    JOIN (
        SELECT l1.market, l1.ask, l1.timestamp FROM trade_data l1 
    ) a ON a.market = c.market AND a.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE(c.timestamp), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(c.timestamp), INTERVAL 100 HOUR), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")
```

Expected result based on the SQLFiddle above would be:

```
id | trade_cost_at_time | timestamp | next_hour_top_price | next_hour_top_price_time

1604 | 0.00001212 | 2017-12-15 16:30:03 | 0.00001220
1804 | 0.00001220 | 2017-12-15 16:40:02 | 0.00001218
2004 | 0.00001218 | 2017-12-15 17:00:02 | 0.00001205
...
5588 | 0.00001171 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02 | 0.00001184
...
10777 | 0.00001204 | 2017-12-16 00:10:03 | 0.00001199
11177 | 0.00001199 | NULL | NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. You seem to need to group by trade, and find the max of a certain subset of rows. What does "grouping errors" mean? What did you try? What even identifies a "trade" in that table in the sense that it is a thing with a time & heights within 10" of that time? Spend more time explaining how the output should look based on the input--as if you were telling someone clearly enough to go away and come back with a program to do that--because you are. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy I've updated the SQLFiddle and put expected results too. The group by errors were around "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by". I don't think putting what I've tried here would be of much benefit and I don't have them to hand anymore.

Comment: Such group by errors are from nonsensically grouping but explaining what you were trying to accomplish by such a step might help explain part of what you want.

Comment: Please address all my 1st comment--explain. So the output is the input plus a max column? What does "that trade" mean? Is the whole table re one "trade"? Why then "all the trades"? How do we know what time & costs (aka prices?) apply to what "trade"? Maybe we group per hour of the day? We must guess from your unclear description. You give data that is voluminous not minimal expecting us to maximize over unexplained groups guessing a pattern while you elide output when we don't yet know it. Why should we try to figure out when you won't guide us? If you can't say in words, how can you in code?

Comment: Instead of the result you expect from your attempts, state the _desired_ result.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't certain about the 10 minute intervals, so I [created a numbers table](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3573/A-MySQL-Tidbit-Quick-Numbers-Table-Generation.html) so I could generate a range of 10 minute intervals. You might not need this, or you might already have an alternative approach. Anyway the following query uses 2 correlated subqueries in 2 stages. The first is to get the `max(ask)` value over the next hour, then the second uses that value to match to `min(timestamp)` in that hour where that price was achieved.

Demonstration available at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74ede7/19)

**Query 1**:

```
select
       *
     , (select min(nxt.timestamp) from trade_data nxt
        where nxt.market = d.market 
             and nxt.timestamp > d.start_time
             and nxt.timestamp < date_add(d.start_time, interval 1 hour) 
             and nxt.ask = d.next_hour_top_price
             limit 1
            ) as next_hour_top_time
from (
      select
            tr.n
          , td.market
          , tr.start_time
          , coalesce(min(td.ask),0) ask
          , count(td.timestamp) num_trades
          , (select max(nxt.ask) from trade_data nxt
            where nxt.market = td.market 
            and nxt.timestamp > tr.start_time
            and nxt.timestamp < date_add(tr.start_time, interval 1 hour) 
            limit 1
            ) as next_hour_top_price
      from (
             -- generate table of time ranges
             select n
                  , date_add(str_to_date('2017-12-15 16:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), interval (n*10) minute) as start_time
                  , date_add(str_to_date('2017-12-15 16:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), interval ((n+1)*10) minute) as end_time
             from numbers
             where n between 0 and 60
             ) tr
      left outer join trade_data td on td.timestamp >= tr.start_time and td.timestamp < tr.end_time
      group by tr.n, td.market, tr.start_time
      ) d
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74ede7/19/0)**:

```
|  n |     market |       start_time |        ask | next_hour_top_price |   next_hour_top_time |
|----|------------|------------------|------------|---------------------|----------------------|
|  0 |     (null) | 2017-12-15 16:00 |          0 |              (null) |               (null) |
|  1 |     (null) | 2017-12-15 16:10 |          0 |              (null) |               (null) |
|  2 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 16:20 | 0.00001212 |           0.0000122 | 2017-12-15 16:30:03Z |
|  3 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 16:30 |  0.0000122 |           0.0000122 | 2017-12-15 16:30:03Z |
|  4 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 16:40 | 0.00001218 |          0.00001218 | 2017-12-15 16:40:02Z |
|  5 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 16:50 | 0.00001201 |          0.00001205 | 2017-12-15 17:00:02Z |
|  6 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 17:00 | 0.00001205 |          0.00001205 | 2017-12-15 17:00:02Z |
|  7 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 17:10 | 0.00001204 |          0.00001204 | 2017-12-15 17:10:02Z |
|  8 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 17:20 | 0.00001194 |            0.000012 | 2017-12-15 18:00:02Z |
|  9 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 17:30 |  0.0000118 |            0.000012 | 2017-12-15 18:00:02Z |
| 10 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 17:40 | 0.00001191 |            0.000012 | 2017-12-15 18:00:02Z |
| 11 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 17:50 | 0.00001199 |            0.000012 | 2017-12-15 18:00:02Z |
| 12 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 18:00 |   0.000012 |            0.000012 | 2017-12-15 18:00:02Z |
| 13 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 18:10 | 0.00001176 |          0.00001188 | 2017-12-15 18:20:02Z |
| 14 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 18:20 | 0.00001188 |          0.00001188 | 2017-12-15 18:20:02Z |
| 15 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 18:30 | 0.00001182 |          0.00001182 | 2017-12-15 18:30:02Z |
| 16 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 18:40 | 0.00001181 |          0.00001181 | 2017-12-15 18:40:03Z |
| 17 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 18:50 | 0.00001173 |          0.00001174 | 2017-12-15 19:30:02Z |
| 18 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 19:00 | 0.00001152 |          0.00001174 | 2017-12-15 19:30:02Z |
| 19 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 19:10 | 0.00001151 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 20:00:02Z |
| 20 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 19:20 |  0.0000117 |          0.00001184 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02Z |
| 21 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 19:30 | 0.00001174 |          0.00001184 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02Z |
| 22 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 19:40 | 0.00001171 |          0.00001184 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02Z |
| 23 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 19:50 | 0.00001172 |          0.00001184 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02Z |
| 24 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 20:00 | 0.00001183 |          0.00001184 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02Z |
| 25 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 20:10 | 0.00001184 |          0.00001184 | 2017-12-15 20:10:02Z |
| 26 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 20:20 | 0.00001175 |          0.00001181 | 2017-12-15 21:00:02Z |
| 27 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 20:30 | 0.00001169 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 21:20:02Z |
| 28 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 20:40 | 0.00001169 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 21:20:02Z |
| 29 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 20:50 | 0.00001173 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 21:20:02Z |
| 30 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 21:00 | 0.00001181 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 21:20:02Z |
| 31 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 21:10 | 0.00001181 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 21:20:02Z |
| 32 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 21:20 | 0.00001183 |          0.00001183 | 2017-12-15 21:20:02Z |
| 33 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 21:30 |  0.0000118 |          0.00001198 | 2017-12-15 22:20:02Z |
| 34 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 21:40 |  0.0000118 |            0.000012 | 2017-12-15 22:30:02Z |
| 35 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 21:50 |  0.0000118 |           0.0000122 | 2017-12-15 22:40:02Z |
| 36 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 22:00 | 0.00001179 |           0.0000124 | 2017-12-15 22:50:02Z |
| 37 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 22:10 |  0.0000118 |           0.0000124 | 2017-12-15 22:50:02Z |
| 38 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 22:20 | 0.00001198 |           0.0000124 | 2017-12-15 22:50:02Z |
| 39 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 22:30 |   0.000012 |           0.0000124 | 2017-12-15 22:50:02Z |
| 40 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 22:40 |  0.0000122 |           0.0000124 | 2017-12-15 22:50:02Z |
| 41 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 22:50 |  0.0000124 |           0.0000124 | 2017-12-15 22:50:02Z |
| 42 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 23:00 | 0.00001219 |          0.00001219 | 2017-12-15 23:00:03Z |
| 43 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 23:10 | 0.00001208 |          0.00001211 | 2017-12-15 23:50:02Z |
| 44 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 23:20 | 0.00001194 |          0.00001211 | 2017-12-15 23:50:02Z |
| 45 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 23:30 | 0.00001209 |          0.00001211 | 2017-12-15 23:50:02Z |
| 46 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 23:40 | 0.00001209 |          0.00001211 | 2017-12-15 23:50:02Z |
| 47 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-15 23:50 | 0.00001211 |          0.00001211 | 2017-12-15 23:50:02Z |
| 48 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-16T00:00 | 0.00001204 |          0.00001204 | 2017-12-16T00:00:02Z |
| 49 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-16T00:10 | 0.00001199 |          0.00001199 | 2017-12-16T00:10:03Z |
| 50 | STOCK-NAME | 2017-12-16T00:20 | 0.00001199 |          0.00001199 | 2017-12-16T00:20:02Z |
```

setup

```
CREATE TABLE `trade_data` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `market` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ask` decimal(20,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11374 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `trade_data` (`id`, `market`, `ask`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
    (1604, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001212, '2017-12-15 16:20:02'),
    (1804, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001220, '2017-12-15 16:30:03'),
    (2004, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001218, '2017-12-15 16:40:02'),
    (2204, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001201, '2017-12-15 16:50:02'),
    (2404, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001205, '2017-12-15 17:00:02'),
    (2603, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001204, '2017-12-15 17:10:02'),
    (2802, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001194, '2017-12-15 17:20:02'),
    (3001, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001180, '2017-12-15 17:30:04'),
    (3200, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001191, '2017-12-15 17:40:02'),
    (3399, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001199, '2017-12-15 17:50:02'),
    (3598, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001200, '2017-12-15 18:00:02'),
    (3797, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001176, '2017-12-15 18:10:03'),
    (3996, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001188, '2017-12-15 18:20:02'),
    (4195, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001182, '2017-12-15 18:30:02'),
    (4394, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001181, '2017-12-15 18:40:03'),
    (4593, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001173, '2017-12-15 18:50:02'),
    (4792, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001152, '2017-12-15 19:00:02'),
    (4991, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001151, '2017-12-15 19:10:03'),
    (5190, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001170, '2017-12-15 19:20:02'),
    (5389, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001174, '2017-12-15 19:30:02'),
    (5588, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001171, '2017-12-15 19:40:03'),
    (5787, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001172, '2017-12-15 19:50:02'),
    (5986, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001183, '2017-12-15 20:00:02'),
    (6185, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001184, '2017-12-15 20:10:02'),
    (6384, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001175, '2017-12-15 20:20:03'),
    (6583, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001169, '2017-12-15 20:30:02'),
    (6782, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001169, '2017-12-15 20:40:03'),
    (6981, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001173, '2017-12-15 20:50:02'),
    (7180, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001181, '2017-12-15 21:00:02'),
    (7379, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001181, '2017-12-15 21:10:03'),
    (7578, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001183, '2017-12-15 21:20:02'),
    (7777, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001180, '2017-12-15 21:30:02'),
    (7977, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001180, '2017-12-15 21:40:02'),
    (8177, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001180, '2017-12-15 21:50:03'),
    (8377, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001179, '2017-12-15 22:00:02'),
    (8577, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001180, '2017-12-15 22:10:02'),
    (8777, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001198, '2017-12-15 22:20:02'),
    (8977, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001200, '2017-12-15 22:30:02'),
    (9177, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001220, '2017-12-15 22:40:02'),
    (9377, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001240, '2017-12-15 22:50:02'),
    (9577, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001219, '2017-12-15 23:00:03'),
    (9777, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001208, '2017-12-15 23:10:03'),
    (9977, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001194, '2017-12-15 23:20:02'),
    (10177, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001209, '2017-12-15 23:30:02'),
    (10377, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001209, '2017-12-15 23:40:02'),
    (10577, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001211, '2017-12-15 23:50:02'),
    (10777, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001204, '2017-12-16 00:00:02'),
    (10977, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001199, '2017-12-16 00:10:03'),
    (11177, 'STOCK-NAME', 0.00001199, '2017-12-16 00:20:02');


-- create numbers table structure (very basic)
create table `numbers` (
  `n` int(11) not null,
  primary key (`n`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
-- insert generated number sequence (e.g., 1-1,000,000)
insert into `numbers`(n)
select @rownum:=@rownum+1
from (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) a, (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) b, (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) c, (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) d, (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) e, (
   select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
   union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
   union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
) f, (select @rownum:=-1) r
;
```